# Devemos editar publicações de SPAM?

Tags: debate

Ontem foi publicada uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327755/5878) SPAM em uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27859/5878) que, por sinal, foi a segunda vez que aconteceu.

Como de costume, não só meu, mas de vários outros usuários, editei a resposta a fim de não manter visível o conteúdo até que a mesma fosse excluída. Acontece que um gringo solicitou que eu revertesse a edição, para que o conteúdo ficasse visível devido ao *bot* não oficial contra SPAM: [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey).

Ele ainda argumentou citando a pergunta no meta: [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/369699) Nas respostas é argumentado que publicações de SPAM não deveriam ser editadas, principalmente porque se a edição for revertida as sinalizações feitas após a edição são perdidas.

Eu não vejo isso como problema, pois geralmente fazemos essas edições quando a publicação é inteiramente SPAM, que não tem salvação, então dificilmente a edição será revertida. Quando é apenas um link na resposta que pode ser SPAM, a edição é feita apenas removendo o conteúdo suspeito, mantendo o que dá para salvar da resposta, então também a edição dificilmente seria revertida.

Resumindo, não vejo uma situação em que a edição fosse maléfica para a comunidade.

O que vocês acham?

Comment: A edição pode ser revertida pelo AP logo de seguida. Parece-me que será esse o problema.

Comment: Eu acho que, se as sinalizações de spam desaparecem após uma edição, eu diria pra simplesmente sinalizar e votar pra fechar o mais rapido possível. Enquanto eu concordo que deixar o controle de spam a cargo de uma ferramenta não oficial é ruim, é bom guardar registros dessas comunicações para argumentar depois caso algum problema sobre contenção de SPAM ocorra aqui.

Comment: Acho que precisaria de mais contexto, inclusive de quem disse pra fazer isso, afinal quem diz pra fazer algo diferente deve justificar. Eu não vi motivo para não fazer na mão, mas pode ser só ignorância minha.

Comment: Eu acho que depende só da situação. Geralmente eu deixo como está, até para o pessoal votar como spam mesmo, mas edito quando é fechada por outros motivos por engano. (ai faço as 2 coisas, a edição tirando ou mais "maldosamente" :P quebrando o link, só para combater a eficácia do spam, mas sem descaracterizar). Tem que ver caso a caso mesmo, acredito eu. Por exemplo, pedido de serviço com divulgação de telefone e email, eu vejo da mesma forma. Até oriento nos comentários quando é aquela coisa mais "inocente", mas sempre buscando que a atitude não compense para não incentivar a prática